# why I can not ping another host through the router

Tags: networking, routes, ip, cisco

[image: my topology]

I'm doing my homework about FLSM with Cisco packet tracer, so after i configure addresses of routers and hosts I find that when pc0(11.1.1.1) ping pc2(11.3.1.1) which it can't get response from. I have set the Rip as 11.0.0.0 and clock state for the dce. So what's the problem????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the rip on both routers, default GWs, correct masks on hosts, no shutdown ports, turn on routers, use rip version 2 and no autosummary on rip.
Set the rip 11.1.0.0 and 11.0.0.0 on R1 and 11.3.0.0 and 11.0.0.0 on R2.